Is this a bell pepper plant?
The tag has yolo Wonder Pepper but these do not look like bell peppers. Any idea?


@YosefBaskin The shape looks wrong for either. Jalapeno's are smooth with a blunt, rounded tip, also usually much darker and smaller than this. The banana pepper would have a more conical shape with a pointed tip.

Based on what I've grown and eaten (although in Europe), I'd guess a hybrid similar to a bell pepper, medium wall thickness, sweet, hardly any spice if at all once you get the seeds out, ripens red, but good while still green (they call it "technical" vs "botanical" ripeness here). The one on the top right looks like an ideal candidate for tasting right now :) I envy you, mine are just starting to show the first flowers.

Its definately not a bell pepper, but it may be a capsicum (possibly something like a Marconi or Banana Pepper or some hybrid - but I could be wrong on this part. It is possible it is not a Capsicum and its possible it could be hot.)
I did once inherit a plant that looked similar.  It had a peppery bite (but was not very hot)
Regardless, Yolo Wonder Pepper IS a Bell pepper, and this plant is not a Wonder Pepper - that label does not belong to that plant.

Bell peppers aka capsicums come in many shapes and sizes. Sometimes it is hard to tell without tasting them. I have had capsicums that look like that.
Cross pollination with a neighbouring chilli plant can also affect size, colour, shape and heat of the fruit.

I believe Bell peppers are a type of Capsicum - and while this is probably a capsicum its not a bell pepper cultivar - https://www.kingsseeds.co.nz/collections/capsicums  shows a few cultivars of capsicum which are not bell peppers. (Alsohttps://differencebtw.com/bell-peppers-vs-capsicum/ ).
